# HTML CSS - Adding curves on div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a mockup and needed help with this particular section.

Image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYG5b.jpg

What is the best practice to get these "curvy" lines on top and bottom of my divs? Should I do it as an after element? If so should I have it as an image or can I use some kind of transform?

I'm trying to figure out the best option that's also responsive.

Comment: You can use svg image for achieve this.

Comment: @FluffyKitten nice find! Let me give this a shot!